# How to implement NumberFormatter with UWP NumberBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `NumberBox` control in my UWP project.

I want to use it to display a number of minutes, so I want the number on the box to be followed by "min" (e.g. "10 min").

I thought I could implement this using a `NumberFormatter`, but don't know how.

This is what I tried:

1. Added `NumberFormatter` class

```cs
public class DurationFormatter : INumberFormatter2
{
    public string FormatInt(long value)
    {
        return $"{value} min";
    }

    public string FormatDouble(double value)
    {
        return $"{value} min";
    }

    public string FormatUInt(ulong value)
    {
        return $"{value} min";
    }
}
```

2. Added reference to page resources

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local1:DurationFormatter x:Key="Converter1"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

3. Tried to add formatter to number box, but not sure how. This doesn't work:

```xml
<muxc:NumberBox x:Name="DurationNumberBox" SpinButtonPlacementMode="Compact" 
                Header="Duration" Value="{x:Bind DurationViewValue, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                ValidationMode="InvalidInputOverwritten" 
                NumberFormatter="{StaticResource Converter1}"/>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I've only used UWP a little, but I'm pretty sure `{StaticResource=Converter1}` should be `{StaticResource Converter1}`.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the typo. Still doesn't work.

Comment: The WinUI team is actively answering questions about WinUI controls in [Github issues](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues)

Comment: I don't think this is an "issue", it's just I don't know how to do it. Documentation is a bit sparse on this...

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, I haven't. Ended up using a label after the number box...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue for a while, and it turns out the issue is that the converter class has to implement `INumberFormatter2` and `INumberParser`. This isn't documented anywhere except [in this comment in the source code of the `NumberBox`](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/main/dev/NumberBox/NumberBox.cpp#L306).